# Как вывести на одну страницу две модели из базы данных?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Мне надо вывести данные из двух таблиц базы данных на одну страницу.
Пока у меня получается вывести данные только из одной таблицы.

Вот что есть:

Модель1:

```
public class Match
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Team1 { get; set; }
    public string Team2 { get; set; }
    public int Rate { get; set; }
    public int BO { get; set; }
}
```

Модель2:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Days { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Контекст данных:

```
public class MatchContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Match> Matches { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

Контроллер:

```
public class NeuroController : Controller
{

    MatchContext db = new MatchContext();        
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db);
    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

И в представлении:

```
@model IEnumerable<NB.Models.Match>
@{
...
```

**Как вывести на страницу модели "Match" и "Person" ?**

Comment: @Bald Я создал такую модель, потом в контроллере добавил
`MatchPersonViewModel db = new MatchPersonViewModel();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db);
        }`
И в представлении 
`@model IEnumerable<NB.Models.MatchPersonViewModel>` 
Но все ровно не удается обратится к таблице

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Добавил ссылку на пример для ViewModel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чуть более подробно про способы предложенные @DreamChild

Создадим модель в которой будут содержаться необходимые для представления данные:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Match> Matches {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<Person> Persons {get;set;}

    //или же можно указать конкретные свойства из классов
}
```

в методе вызывающим данное представление необходимо получить необходимые данные и создать экземпляр **ViewModel** заполнить его и отдать в представление

```
public class NeuroController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult GetViewModel()
    {
        var db = new MatchContext();
        var matches = db.Matches.ToList();
        var persons = db.Persons.ToList();
        var model = new ViewModel { Matches = matches, Persons = persons};
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

в качестве модели в представлении необходимо указать созданную нами **ViewModel**: `@model ViewModel`

обращения к `Matches` | `Persons` в представлении будет выглядеть как: `@Model.`, т.е. `@Model.Matches` | `@Model.Persons`

[Пример](https://dotnetfiddle.net/atK0iB)

---

Вариант с частичными представлениями реализуется следующим образом:

1. Для каждого класса который необходимо создать частичное представление:
   т.е. в вашем случае создаете *частичное представление* для `Match` & `Person`;
2. Методы в контроллере должны возвращать *частичное представление*: `return PartialView(model);`(в чем отличие `View()` & `PartialView()` можно посмотреть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4210291/5610621))
3. В представлении *MatchPerson* необходимо будет вызвать метод `@Html.RenderAction` который вернет *частичное представление*;

---

Пример *частичного представления* для вывода списка `Person`:

```
@model IEnumerable<Person>    
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Days)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)</th>
    </tr>    
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Days)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)</td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Пример метода контролера

```
public ActionResult GetPersons()
{
    var persons = db.Persons.ToList();
    return PartialView(persons);    
}
```

где то в представлении для отображения двух моделей

```
//html разметка
@Html.RenderActions("GetPersons")
//html разметка
```

Comment: В первом варианте, когда я пытаюсь указать модель в представлении
`@model ViewModel` 
Пишет, что не удалось найти тип или пространство имен ViewModel.

(Делал так же, как вы написали)

Comment: @PavelBlokhin добавьте в вопрос созданную вами  *ViewModel*

Comment: Такая же как и увас
`public class ViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Match> Matches {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<Person> Persons {get;set;}
}`

Comment: @PavelBlokhin покажите метод контроллера где Вы заполняете модель и отдаете её *представлению*

Comment: Вот так выглядит контроллер 
`MatchContext db = new MatchContext();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var matches = db.Matches.ToList();
            var persons = db.Persons.ToList();
            var model = new ViewModel { Matches = matches, Persons = persons };
            return View(model);
        }`

Answer (score 4):

Либо сделайте, чтобы ваша страница состояла из двух отдельных частичных представлений, у каждого из которых будет модель соответствующего класса, либо, если этот вариант неприменим, создайте одну убер-модель, включающую в себя экземпляры обоих классов (или необходимые поля из обоих классов)

Comment: Как будет выглядеть эта убер-модель?

Comment: @PavelBlokhin как класс с двумя свойствами. Или даже просто полями.